# Grouping, Clustering, Classification and Predective

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I am working with Elasticsearch and kibanba for analyzing data. 
Does anybody know is it possible to cluster data based on ...(whatever) in elasticsearch or kibana?

Clustering or Classification, or groupping. 
for example like machine learning to give it some samples and then it can understand the trend for other data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch Hadoop contains an Elasticsearch Spark connector. You could run a Spark job on Elasticsearch data and  use Spark MLLib for the machine learning stuff.